# android statelistdrawable to cause button to shrink and then go back to original size

Tags: android, xml, bounce, statelistdrawable

I am trying to use my xml file to add a drawable to a button so that it gives the bounce affect. It's resting state size should be 1x1. When you click on it, it should go from 1 to 0.75, and then back from 0.75 to 1 so that it looks like a bounce.

I want the default state to basically be nothing (other code causes the default state to get triggered and the bounce will happen when i dont want it to).

So, I need 3 states. 1 for pressed, 1 to go back to the default, and one that is the default.

Is there any other state that I can use so that the button gets smaller, and then bigger again looking like a bounce without using default?

Codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item> <!-- default state -->
        <set android:ordering="together">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="75"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueFrom="1"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="75"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueFrom="1"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"> <!-- pressed state -->
        <set android:ordering="together">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="75"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueFrom="1"
                android:valueTo="0.25"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="75"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueFrom="1"
                android:valueTo="0.25"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>

    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true"> <!-- selected state -->
        <set android:ordering="together">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="75"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueFrom="0.25"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="75"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueFrom="0.25"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these states for default state:

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    ...>
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Thank you =) That worked perfectly